# Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '() => Map<String, dynamic>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm developing web app with flutter using Firebase cloud firestore.

I want to get values from firestore, but error occurs and can't get them.

Error;

> Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '() => Map<String, dynamic>?'

Code;

```
  Future<String> getData(String collection, String field) async {
    DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collection).doc().get();
    Map<String, dynamic> record = docSnapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return record[field];
  }


FutureBuilder(
              future: getData("users", "userName"),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                  return const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return SelectableText(snapshot.error.toString());
                }

                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Text('No data found');
                }

                return Text('${snapshot.data}');
              },
            )
```

This code is FutureBuilder that calls `getData()` and displays an error statement on the screen when an error occurs.

---

After a bit of research, I found a way to get rid of the error this way. code like this;

```
Map<String,dynamic> record = new Map<String,dynamic>.from(docSnapshot.data["songs"]);
```

However, this is grammatically incorrect and will result in a compilation error.
Firestore seems to have changed a lot between 2019 and now, is that the cause?

```
docSnapshot.data["songs"]
```

This is not valid for `DocumentSnapshot`.

Can anyone resolve this error? thank you.

### Addition 1;

I changed code but other similar error occurred.
The first error has been resolved.

```
    Map<String, dynamic> record = docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

> Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type
> 'Null'

Firestore confirmed that the data "userName" was existed correctly.

[image: Img1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `DocumentSnapshot.data` is a method, so you should change it to: `DocumentSnapshot.data()`

Comment: It should be `docSnapshot.data.data()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed code but other error occurred.
I edited the question.

Comment: @Mudassir Hi, Where to write them? In my environment,  `data` of `docSnapshot` doesn't have `data()` method.

Comment: Ok, I believe here is what is happening: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collection).doc()` will get the `collection` collection and will create a new document in it, after that, you get the document and try to get its data, which is empty, so data() returns null.

Comment: Why I get empty data? The image in question shows that it has field in uid document.　If you have time, please.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm not mistaken, which I could be, but if I'm not, what your code does is create a new document in a given collection (in this case users) and then attempts to read a value on that document. If you don't tell firestore what you wish to read, it will assume you just want to read a new document. The way to fix this would be to pass the name of the document you wish to read like so: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collection).doc(document).get();` and add a parameter `String document` to your function. then when calling it, pass a UID to that parameter